# vSphere API to create a vApp VM with SDRS

Tags: go, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to create a VM within a vApp and use SDRS in Go using the govmomi package, but haven't been able to figure out a way to do it in one step.

Based on the tasks in vCenter (when I do it through the vCenter web client), it seems to be possible. Using the API, if I use SDRS recommendations, I get an error about the resource pool not being valid (because its actually a vApp), but if I use the VM creation process with the vApp, I don't get the SDRS benefits (and can't actually use a datastore cluster at all since a datastore is required).

To work around it, I could either get a recommendation for SDRS and just pull the datastore info out if it instead of applying and then creating the VM through the vApp, or I could create the VM outside of the vApp using SDRS and move it into the vApp afterward, but these both seem hacky.

I'm looking to see if there is a way to do what appears to be happening in vCenter, and avoid one of the hacky workarounds.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow because it is not about programming. You should ask in a different stackexchange forum.

Comment: If I specify asking how to do it using the govmomi Go package is it ok?